# INSERT ALL statement in Oracle failing to insert

Tags: oracle

I have multiple rows to insert in a table.
There are some constraints in the table which fails for few of the rows.
But with INSERT ALL statement, when it finds the first insert with constraint fails, it stops inserting to oracle db and rest of the data which are proper is also not inserted.
Will it be working this way only. Or do we have any method in which insert all valid data and ignore the other inserts in the INSERT ALL.

Comment: can you post the query ?

Comment: As @mmhasannn already mentioned - please post the DDL statement for all tables you're trying to INSERT into, as well as your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when it finds the first insert with constraint fails, it stops inserting to oracle db and rest of the data which are proper is also not inserted. Will it be working this way only.

Yes, it is designed to work that way. **INSERT ALL** statement will fail to insert *if any one row errors out*.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_unique UNIQUE(a);

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES(1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO t (a) VALUES (1)
  3    INTO t (a) VALUES (2)
  4    INTO t (a) VALUES (3)
  5  SELECT * FROM dual;
INSERT ALL
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.T_UNIQUE) violated    

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1
```

If you want other values to be inserted which are correct, then put them as individual insert statements and execute all the insert statements as a **script**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_unique UNIQUE(a);

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES(1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.T_UNIQUE) violated    

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(2);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(3);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Comment: Thank you, i am currently inserting as single insert statements via script. But wanted to try INSERT ALL, but was failing because of certain rows are having violations.

Comment: You could achieve exception handling in PL/SQL, however, in SQL the INSERT ALL statement is one single transaction. Either all rows are inserted or none. It is the basic rule of atomicity.